# Updating DOM with MathJax and Vue.js

Tags: javascript, html, mathjax, vue.js

(Edited to include a work-around, but the original problem still stands)

I've got an HTML page I'm trying to create using Vue.js (for its nice and easy components and whatnot) and MathJax (to layout math equations, obviously) but they are not playing nice together. I have found some talk about this issue w/r/t Angular (another web technology similar to Vue, in my limited understanding) but nothing about Vue and MathJax.

I realize the problem has to do with Vue manipulating the HTML DOM directly, and MathJax not realizing it/dealing with it. There are some methods in MathJax that purport to help with this, but either they don't work or I'm not using them correctly.

Herewith is my attempt at a minimal example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <script src='https://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML'></script>
 <title>Vue and Mathjax Failing Together</title>
</head>

<body>
<h2>Vue and Mathjax Failing Together</h2>

<div id="app">

<p>The MathJax string renders OK in a Vue data binding (shown using "triple mustache" notation because it's got HTML in it)</p>
{{{ mathjax_paragraph }}}
<hr>

<button v-on:click="createDynamicMarkup">Click to show {{ show_math ? "HTML":"MathJax" }} markup</button>
<p>Here is the dynamic element:</p>
<div id="dynamic_markup_div">
{{{ dynamic_markup }}}
</div>

<br>
<br>
<hr>
<pre>
APP DATA = {{ $data | json }}
</pre>

</div>

<script src='vue.js'></script>
<script>
 new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
   html_paragraph: "<p><i>This is plain HTML</i></p>",
   mathjax_paragraph: "<p>\\begin{eqnarray*} \\frac{20}{3}=6.66= 6\\mbox{ hours and } 40 \\mbox{ minutes}. \\end{eqnarray*} </p>",
   dynamic_markup: "<p><i>plain HTML</i></p>",
   show_math: false,

   math_thing: 0,
   },
  methods: {
   createDynamicMarkup: function(event) {
    this.show_math = !this.show_math;
    if (this.show_math) {
     this.dynamic_markup = this.mathjax_paragraph;

    // After a short delay, tell MathJax to update. (So short it's zero!)
    // as per https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mathjax-users/EEg35NK2wXU
     MathJax.Hub.Queue(
       ["Delay", MathJax.Callback, 0],
       ["Typeset", MathJax.Hub, "dynamic_markup_div"]
     );

     }
    else {
     this.dynamic_markup = this.html_paragraph;
     }
    },
   },
  });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

When you first load the page, the plain-old HTML is shown; click the button, and the MathJax is supposed to be shown. Except it's not rendered as math (except *sometimes* - see below).

EDIT: I found a work-around, adding a delay (of zero milliseconds!) and then a forced update, which works - but should it be necessary?

[image]

Anyway, any suggestions would be most appreciated!

/rob

Comment: A technical comment: if you're writing HTML5, which your `<doctype html>` claims you do, you don't need `.../>` for void elements like `<link>`, `<br>`, etc. Also, don't use `<br>` for spacing, use CSS =) Finally, you're missing an opening `<html>`. Also, how are you testing this? From `file:///` or using a real http server? (If the first, try using something like node's `http-server` or `python -m SimpleHTTPServer` first, because file:/// is impossibly unpredictable)

Comment: Thanks, Mike, I'll try those suggestions and see what effect, if any, they have.

Comment: Nope - tried all that, no change. Thanks anyway!

Comment: another thing to try is to put the `<script>` element for loading mathjax before `</body>`: right now it loads, and then immediately tries to style the page, which will not have content yet.

Comment: Note from the future: cdn.mathjax.org is nearing its end-of-life, check https://www.mathjax.org/cdn-shutting-down/ for migration tips.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Caveat emptor: I don't know vue.js much.

But it looks like a race condition. You're telling MathJax to render new content but the DOM does not yet have new content.

From a quick look at the vue.js docs, it seems [$nextTick](http://012.vuejs.org/api/instance-methods.html#vm-%5C$nextTick(_callback_)) should help. E.g., wrap it around a typesetting call:

```
                this.$nextTick(function() {
                     MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Typeset", MathJax.Hub]);
                 });
```

Here's a snippet (based on the one you posted to the MathJax User Group).

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<!-- Why does MathJax sometimes not render under Vue?
   robcranfill@ "gee-mail" .com
 -->

<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.0/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML'></script>
 <title>Vue and Mathjax Failing Together</title>
</head>

<body>
<h2>Vue and Mathjax Failing Together</h2>

<div id="app">

<p>The MathJax string renders OK in a Vue data binding (shown using "triple mustache" notation because it's got HTML in it)</p>
{{{ mathjax_paragraph }}}
<hr/>

<button v-on:click="createDynamicMarkup">Click to show {{ show_math ? "HTML":"MathJax" }} markup</button>
<p>Here is the dynamic element:</p>
<div id="dynamic_markup_div">
{{{ dynamic_markup }}}
</div>

<br/>
<br/>
<hr/>
<pre>
APP DATA = {{ $data | json }}
</pre>

</div>

<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/1.0.10/vue.min.js'></script>
<script>
 new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
   html_paragraph: "<p><i>This is plain HTML</i></p>",
   mathjax_paragraph: "<p>\\begin{eqnarray*} \\frac{20}{3}=6.66= 6\\mbox{ hours and } 40 \\mbox{ minutes}. \\end{eqnarray*} </p>",
   dynamic_markup: "<p><i>plain HTML</i></p>",
   show_math: false,

   math_thing: 0,
   },
  methods: {
   createDynamicMarkup: function(event) {
    this.show_math = !this.show_math;
    if (this.show_math) {
     this.dynamic_markup = this.mathjax_paragraph;

     // Update the whole doc? doesn't work (except in the Javascript debugger! Step over this code and it works!)
     // console.log("hello");
     // MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Typeset", MathJax.Hub]);
     this.$nextTick(function() {
       MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Typeset", MathJax.Hub]);
      });

     // Update just the DOM element in question? doesn't work
//     MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Typeset", MathJax.Hub, "dynamic_markup_div"]);

     // Update just the *math* element in question? doesn't work
//     math = MathJax.Hub.getAllJax("dynamic_markup_div")[0];
//     MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Text", math, this.mathjax_paragraph]);

     }
    else {
     this.dynamic_markup = this.html_paragraph;
     }
    },
   },
  });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sweet! That does indeed seem to do the trick. I had not thought to look for the solution in the Vue library (duh!). Plus, your solution actually runs correctly via "Run code snippet" here. Very cool.

Comment: I've updated the answer since cdn.mathjax.org is nearing its end-of-life, cf. https://www.mathjax.org/cdn-shutting-down/.

Comment: Peter, I have never met you, but I love you. This just saved me so many headaches.

Comment: Glad to hear this still helps. Nowadays (with MathJax v3), you should be able to write to vue's virtual dom directly by creating an "adapter" (in mathjax 3 speak); but then again it's so fast now you probably won't notice its rendering in a dynamic setting anymore.